# notificaciones en el escritorio a partir de node.js

Tags: javascript, php, html5, nodejs

Tengo un chat programado con `Node.js`, `PHP` y `MySQL`, solo me falta que notifique al usuario que tiene mensajes nuevos, pero las notificaciones de `HTML5` se desvanecen.

¿Alguien sabe si es posible programarlas como notificaciones de escritorio? o bien, algún modo de que no se desvanezcan?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor añade qué has intentado hasta el momento _Ejemplo: `código fuente, referencias, etc`_

Answer (score 1):

¿Tú chat es una app web o de escritorio? Para conseguir notificaciones de escritorio necesitarías montarla como una app de escritorio.

Para montar aplicaciones de escritorio y multiplataforma una muy buena opción es [Electron](http://electron.atom.io) de [Github](https://github.com/electron/electron)

Comment: Por el momento es una aplicacion web, pero parece que si voy a tener que montarla en electron jajaja. Solo una pregunta, las notificaciones en escritorio aparecerian tambien en iOS??? Saludos!!!

Comment: Ahí me pillas. Quizá alguno de los cracks que hay por aquí nos lo puede aclarar.

Comment: Esto te ayudaría : https://github.com/ttsvetko/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications , aquí un ejemplo : http://ttsvetko.github.io/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications/